# Backbone.js model caching

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

**Note** : I am a very very beginer on Backbone platform !! :)

I have this Model in Backbone:

```
var errors_model    =   Backbone.Model.extend(
{
        total_errors     : 0,
        error_messages   : {},
        initialize       : function ()
        {
            this.set('total_errors',        0);
            this.set('error_messages',      {});
        },
        add_error        : function (tab, field, error)
        {
            var error_messages = this.get('error_messages');
            var error_md5 = this.md5(error);

            if(!(tab in error_messages))
            {
                error_messages[tab] =   {};
            }

            if(!(field in error_messages[tab]))
            {
                error_messages[tab][field]  =   {};
            }

            if(!(error_md5 in error_messages[tab][field]))
            {
                error_messages[tab][field][error_md5]   =   error;
            }

            this.set('error_messages', error_messages);
            this.increase_errors();
            console.log(error_messages);
        },
        remove_error     : function (tab, field, error)
        {
            var error_messages  =   this.get('error_messages');
            var error_md5       =   this.md5(error);

            if(!(tab in error_messages) && !(field in error_messages[tab]) && !(error_md5 in error_messages[tab][field]))
            {
                return;
            }

            delete error_messages[tab][field][error_md5];

            this.set('error_messages',  error_messages);
            this.decrease_errors();
            console.log(error_messages);
        },
        increase_errors  : function()
        {
            var total_errors    =   this.get('total_errors');

            if('undefined' === typeof(total_errors))
            {
                total_errors    =   0;
            }

            ++total_errors;

            this.set('total_errors',    total_errors);
        },
        decrease_errors  : function()
        {
            var total_errors    =   this.get('total_errors');

            if('undefined' === typeof(total_errors))
            {
                total_errors    =   0;
            }

            if(0 === total_errors)
            {
                return;
            }

            --total_errors;

            this.set('total_errors',    total_errors);
        }
    }
);

com                        =   window.com  ||  {};
com.wp                     =   com.wp      ||  {};
com.wp.srb                 =   com.wp.srb  ||  {};
com.wp.srb.errors_model    =   new errors_model();
```

and then I use this code:

```
com.wp.srb.errors_model.add_error('#ad',       '#image_upload',    'This is an error');
com.wp.srb.errors_model.add_error('#ad',       '#image_upload',    'Another error');
com.wp.srb.errors_model.add_error('#ad',       '#image_upload',    'Yet another error');
com.wp.srb.errors_model.add_error('#ad',       '#image_url',       'URL error');

setTimeout(
    function()
    {
        com.wp.srb.errors_model.remove_error('#ad',    '#image_upload',    'Another error');
    },
    3500
);
```

But the result I am getting is this for both action (`com.wp.srb.errors_model.add_error` and `com.wp.srb.errors_model.remove_error`):

```
Object {#ad: Object}
    #ad: Object
        #image_upload: Object
            13b7afb8b11644e17569bd2efb571b10: "This is an error"
            69553926a7783c27f7c18eff55cbd429: "Yet another error"
        #image_url: Object
            2b4a9847e26368312704b8849de9247a: "URL error"
            __proto__: Object
        __proto__: Object
    __proto__: Object

Object {#ad: Object}
    #ad: Object
        #image_upload: Object
            13b7afb8b11644e17569bd2efb571b10: "This is an error"
            69553926a7783c27f7c18eff55cbd429: "Yet another error"
        #image_url: Object
            2b4a9847e26368312704b8849de9247a: "URL error"
            __proto__: Object
        __proto__: Object
    __proto__: Object

Object {#ad: Object}
    #ad: Object
        #image_upload: Object
            13b7afb8b11644e17569bd2efb571b10: "This is an error"
            69553926a7783c27f7c18eff55cbd429: "Yet another error"
        #image_url: Object
            2b4a9847e26368312704b8849de9247a: "URL error"
            __proto__: Object
        __proto__: Object
    __proto__: Object

Object {#ad: Object}
    #ad: Object
        #image_upload: Object
            13b7afb8b11644e17569bd2efb571b10: "This is an error"
            69553926a7783c27f7c18eff55cbd429: "Yet another error"
        #image_url: Object
            2b4a9847e26368312704b8849de9247a: "URL error"
            __proto__: Object
        __proto__: Object
    __proto__: Object

Object {#ad: Object}
    #ad: Object
        #image_upload: Object
            13b7afb8b11644e17569bd2efb571b10: "This is an error"
            69553926a7783c27f7c18eff55cbd429: "Yet another error"
        #image_url: Object
            2b4a9847e26368312704b8849de9247a: "URL error"
            __proto__: Object
        __proto__: Object
    __proto__: Object
```

So the question is, does the Backbone model, somehow caching the object attributes? Am I doing anything wrong?

**NOTE:** This is a part of a plugin that will be used in the WordPress Dashboard, I don't know if WordPress already uses any plugin for caching model data.

Comment: So the problem is that when you add new data to the model, it seems that it has already been added before?

Comment: Yes, that's right. In general I suppose this sould not be happen.

Comment: Does this also happen when you invoke only a singular add_error call? Is the data about other errors there as well?

Comment: Just tryed to run only one "add_error" and I get only one item.

Comment: I would guess this is a problem with console.log being "too slow" and printing the object too late when it has all the fields added.

Comment: Additional, when I did this ...add_error('#ad',       '#image_upload',    'This is an error'); and then I did ...add_error('#ad',       '#image_upload',    'Another error'); in my console I got again only the one error item.

Comment: That would be because of the setTimeout, because you left it there right? Try something like this - instead of using console.log(object), try console.log(JSON.stringify(object)). This will give you a snapshot of the object at the time of execution.

Comment: I don't think so, because later in my console I enter manually the com.wp.srb.errors_model.get('error_messages'); and still display the single message. Even if my console was slow, with later manual advocation of the data should be correct.

Comment: Ok, you are right ! :) Thanks a lot .... If you like, provide an answer to upvote tou ;)

Comment: I wrote up a more clear answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Console holds references to the objects, therefore when you inspect them after the code execution, the state of the object will be as it is right now, not as it is when you invoked:

```
console.log(error_messages);
```

This might work for strings or numbers, but will not work for objects. Thankfully you can turn an object into a string using:

```
JSON.stringify(error_messages);
```

Which will give you a snapshot of the object at the time of execution.